# Using FontAttributes other than Bold and Italic in .NET MAUI

Tags: windows, fonts, maui

I'm trying to use a style of a font that's installed on the Windows system. This font is available in bold and italic but there are also TTF files for light and black and permutations of those. `FontAttributes` is an enum that only allows `None`, `Bold`, and `Italic`, or a combination of those. How do I reference a different style like "Black"?

I need to use fonts installed on the system because a .NET MAUI bug is preventing embedding fonts into an unpackaged app. https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/9104

Comment: Besides FontAttributes, there are TextDecorations. Also, nothing is stopping you from using different FontFamily. (If you do not, there are really annoying bugs on IOS anyway...)

Answer (score 1):

If you want change the font of the windows you can use the `Fontfamily`.

First, you should to register the font file.

```
namespace MyMauiApp
{
    public static class MauiProgram
    {
        public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
        {
            var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
            builder
                .UseMauiApp<App>()
                .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
                {
                    fonts.AddFont("Lobster-Regular.ttf", "Lobster");
                });

            return builder.Build();
        }
    }  
}
```

Second, you can [set font properties per platform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/fonts?view=net-maui-7.0#set-font-properties-per-platform).
The OnPlatform and On classes can be used in XAML to set font properties per platform. The example below sets different font families and sizes:

```
<Label Text="Different font properties on different platforms"
       FontSize="{OnPlatform iOS=20, Android=22, WinUI=24}">
    <Label.FontFamily>
        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String">
            <On Platform="iOS" Value="MarkerFelt-Thin" />
            <On Platform="Android" Value="Lobster-Regular" />
            <On Platform="WinUI" Value="ArimaMadurai-Black" />
        </OnPlatform>
    </Label.FontFamily>
</Label>
```