# MAUI Font Works on Windows Machine But Not In Emulator

Tags: c#, visual-studio, android-emulator, maui

I have a MAUI project and I'm trying to add a custom font in my app. It works when I Run it on windows machine but it does not apply the font while running it from emulator.
does anybody know the reason?
thanks

my custom font is added to Recourses -> Fonts

[image]

I have declared it in MauiProgram Class

[image]

Properties Set For my custom font

[image]

While It is running on windows machine it's correct

[image]

While it is running on android Emulator it is not applied

[image]

I also tried to use another font and it happened again!

Comment: 1) I don't see the code where you *use* the font you declared. 2) Please add code as copy/pastable *text*, not as an image.

Comment: ` <Label
                Text="Hello, World!"
                FontSize="32"
                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                FontFamily="DUELRegular"/>`

Comment: Hi the Code is now working on android emulator but yesterday it was not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't reproduce your problem in my project.

My code in the program.cs:

```
builder
           .UseMauiApp<App>()
           .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
           {
               fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
               fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Semibold.ttf", "OpenSansSemibold");
             fonts.AddFont("Conquest-8MxyM.ttf", "MyFont");
            })
```

And the ttf file:

[image]

Use the font in the xaml:

```
<Label
                Text="Hello, World!"
                SemanticProperties.HeadingLevel="Level1"
                FontSize="32"
                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                FontFamily="MyFont"/>
```

And the result image in the android emulator:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I changed my code and now it's working:

```
    <Label Text="Hello World!"
            FontSize="{OnPlatform iOS=20, Android=22, WinUI=50}">
            <Label.FontFamily>
                <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String">
                    <On Platform="iOS" Value="OpenSans-Regular" />
                    <On Platform="Android" Value="DUEL" />
                    <On Platform="WinUI" Value="OpenSansSemibold" />
                </OnPlatform>
            </Label.FontFamily>
     </Label>
```

This question helped me:

[Using FontAttributes other than Bold and Italic in .NET MAUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75693646/using-fontattributes-other-than-bold-and-italic-in-net-maui)

and **[Guangyu Bai - MSFT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19335715/guangyu-bai-msft)** answer to that question

Comment: But in my project, setting the `FontFamily="DUELRegular"` works on all the platforms. It's a strange behavior.

Comment: the code on android emulator did not work yesterday but now it's working!! I really don't know why LOL