# Font not found (?) in MAUI on Android, works on Windows

Tags: maui

I am building a chess app, using special chess fonts.
In these fonts, chess figurines are assigned to characters. E.g. white King on light square is 'k', white Queen on dark square is 'Q'.

*Some* of these fonts are not found (?) by the maui app on Android. When using these fonts, only the normal characters are shown.
This all works perfectly on "Windows machine" debug or release build. Not so on Android emulator or physical Android device.

Reproduction: Use the MAUI standard app, which is created by VS 2022 on "Create new MAUI solution".
Add this to MainPage.xaml:

```
<VerticalStackLayout x:Name="gChessFonts" RadioButtonGroup.GroupName="chessFonts" Margin="0,2,0,0">
    <RadioButton FontFamily="Chess Adventurer" FontSize="35"  Content="kQrBnP" Value="adven" />
    <RadioButton FontFamily="Chess Merida" FontSize="35" Content="kQrBnP" Value="merid" />
</VerticalStackLayout>
```

And add this to MauiProgram.cs under ConfigureFonts:

```
fonts.AddFont("AVENFONT.TTF", "Chess Adventurer");
fonts.AddFont("MERIFONT.TTF", "Chess Merida");
```

And  add the two ttfs     AVENFONT.TTF and MERIFONT.TTF from  http://www.enpassant.dk/chess/fonteng.htm to the resources/fonts folder.

Result on Android Emulator (or phyiscal device):

[image]

Result on Windows Machine, that's correct:

[image]

I am aware of [MAUI Font Works on Windows Machine But Not In Emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76570751/maui-font-works-on-windows-machine-but-not-in-emulator), which seems to be a duplicate of my problem. But I don't see any solution in the "accepted solution" there. In the "accepted solution" there, another font is used, not the one which caused the problems in the original question.

VS Info:

Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022
Version 17.5.3
VisualStudio.17.Release/17.5.3+33516.290
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.8.09037

Xamarin   17.5.0.173 (d17-5@33e727c)
Visual Studio extension to enable development for Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android.

Xamarin Designer   17.5.3.46 (remotes/origin/d17-5@e4dd80b2bb)
Visual Studio extension to enable Xamarin Designer tools in Visual Studio.

Xamarin.Android SDK   13.2.0.0 (d17-5/797e2e1)
Xamarin.Android Reference Assemblies and MSBuild support.
Mono: 6dd9def
Java.Interop: xamarin/java.interop/main@149d70fe
SQLite: xamarin/sqlite/3.40.0@fdc1e34
Xamarin.Android Tools: xamarin/xamarin-android-tools/main@9f02d77

Answer (score 0):

I did a test on my side with font  `MERIFONT.TTF`, and it is just the case as you said.

But when using `Alpha.ttf` font from the link you shared for testing, this problem does not occur.

So, there should be a compatibility issue with the font you are trying to use(`MERIFONT.TTF`).

Comment: But it works well with the "Windows machine" build.  IMO, it then should work also with the Android build.   I assume MAUI is built to make development easy for different platforms. Which is not the case if they differ in acceptance of fonts!? 
And do not emit any error message!?

Comment: For this, you can create a new issue [here](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/new/choose).